# Generate variables that move information between rows in hierarchical data with spss syntax

Tags: loops, hierarchical-data, spss, recode

I was wondering if you can help me with the following problem in spss syntax.
My dataset has nested structure.

Data are nested in companies, then each company has 1 or 2 bosses, but in this case I care only about boss 1. At a previous stage in time the boss graded the workers (not all of them). Now, the ID and the grade of the workers is on the row each worker.

I would like to move the information that was obtained during worker's assessment and create new sets of variables for each (worker ID and grade) on the line/row of the boss.

```
+---------+------+--------+--------------+---------+---------+--------+---------+
| company | boss |workerID|worker's grade|N:workID1|N:grade1 |N:work2 |N:grade2 |
+---------+------+--------+--------------+---------+---------+--------+---------+
|    A    |   1  |   1    |              |   3     |    A    |   4    |    A    |
|    A    |   2  |   2    |              |         |         |
|    A    |   0  |   3    |       A      |         |         |
|    A    |   0  |   4    |       A      |         |         |
|    A    |   0  |   5    |              |         |         |
|    B    |   1  |   1    |              |    3    |   B     |   4    |    A    |
|    B    |   0  |   2    |              |         |         |
|    B    |   0  |   3    |       B      |         |         |
|    B    |   0  |   4    |       A      |         |         |
|    C    |   1  |   1    |              |    2    |    D    |   -1   |   -1    |
|    C    |   0  |   2    |       D      |         |         |
```

I would like to move the worker's id and the grade that to the row of the boss in the NEW variables, without loosing the existing variables on workerID and worker's grade.

Basically, I will need to feed forward the information into the new variables and to the row of boss EQ 1 separately for each company.

I have no idea how to proceed with this. I assume that I need a loop that creates new variable for each worker ID that has a valid grade and then feeds forward the information from the worker's row to the boss' newly generated variables.
Any suggestions are very wellcome :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at VARSTOCASES (Data > Restructure)

Comment: Thank you for your response. This would turn the long format into wide and perhaps more manageable. However, I was wondering whether it is possible to do it without restructuring the dataset. I found the AGGREGATE command however it exports the dataset into a new format and it applies summary statistics, it doesn't help you to compute variables within a aggregate level/group